# How to search Outlook mails directly from server

Tags: c#, outlook

everybody.
I'm using Microsoft Outlook 15.0 Object Library for working with mail box.

When I search via my code sometimes it not return any result, the same query via Outlook show message:

[more results at server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1y0rI.png)

or

[more results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GMZkw.png)

Tell me please, how to get all results programmatically. It would be nice to get them directly from server.

Now I'm using the following code:

```
 public BindingList<Mail> SearchForEmails(string query, out int resultsCount,  List<string> excludedCategories) 
 {
     resultsCount = 0;
     BindingList<Mail> searchResults = new BindingList<Mail>();
     // Check if Instant Search is enabled and operational in the default store. 
     if (_application.Session.DefaultStore.IsInstantSearchEnabled)
     {
         // Create a new explorer to display the Inbox as 
         // the current folder. 
         Outlook.Explorer explorer = _application.Explorers.Add(_inboxFolder, Outlook.OlFolderDisplayMode.olFolderDisplayNormal);

         // Search for items from the manager marked important, 
         // from all folders of the same item type as the current folder, which is the MailItem item type. 
         explorer.Search(query, Outlook.OlSearchScope.olSearchScopeCurrentFolder);

         // Any search results are displayed in that new explorer 
         // in an aggregated table view. 
         Outlook.TableView tableView = explorer.CurrentView as Outlook.TableView;

         // Use GetTable of that table view to obtain items in that 
         // aggregated view in a Table object. 
         Outlook.Table table = tableView.GetTable();
         resultsCount = table.GetRowCount();
         while (!table.EndOfTable)
         {
              // Then display each row in the Table object 
              // that represents an item in the search results. 
              Outlook.Row nextRow = table.GetNextRow();
              Outlook.MailItem mailItem = _application.Session.GetItemFromID(nextRow["EntryID"]) as Outlook.MailItem;

              searchResults.Add(new Mail(mailItem?.Subject, mailItem?.SenderEmailAddress));

         }
         searchResults.GroupBy(m => m.SenderEmailAddress);
      }
      return searchResults;
 }
```

Comment: Oops) Hello, everybody!)

Comment: Both results you showed show no results, so if outlook itself isnt finding the results then there isnt a lot you can do to change that..  It would suggest what you're looking for isnt there, or isnt in the search

Comment: When it suggest to search in server, after clicking it really shows results. In the second case it loads more results.

Comment: you havent shown that anywhere here..  Or an example of what you're searching for .. eg your query string - if thats not right you wont get results either..

Comment: Just simple query, even one word, without any logic concatinations